# Found solution to my question with some information provided in an answer - what to do now?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I asked this question :
[WPF Slider not working with touch input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517485/wpf-slider-not-working-with-touch-input)

Someone kindly replied, and with the link provided I was able to find the information I needed to solve this problem.

Unfortunately, the solution I found is not related to the rest of his answer. He talks about a property (IsManipulationEnabled), but in my case I just had to handle an event.

So I don't think I can "accept" his answer, because if other people read this, they may not be able to solve the problem.

Should I :

- Write my answer in comment, let him edit his answer and THEN, when it matches exactly my question, accept it,
- Make my own answer, but I don't want to seem like I'm begging for up-votes,
- Something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was helpful, so you can upvote it. Answers need not be complete to be helpful.

If you choose to compose a complete answer, you can post it and mark it as accepted. There is a two-day waiting period before you can accept your own answer, so there is a chance that someone else will provide an even *better* answer in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I already tried to upvote it but I wasn't allowed (less than 15 rep). As you suggested, I will write my own answer.